# If $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},....a_{n}$ are positive real numbers,then

Tags: sequences-and-series

Q) If $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},....a_{n}$ are positive real numbers,then

$\frac{a_{1}}{a_{2}} + \frac{a_{2}}{a_{3}}+......+\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n}}+\frac{a_{n}}{a_{1}}$

is always

(A) $\geq n \;$ (B) $\leq n\;$ (C) $\leq n^{1/n}\;$ (D) none of the above

I have taken some small values of $n$ like $n=2,3$ and sample inputs as $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(2,3,5)$,$(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(1/2,1/3,1/5)$ , $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(0.1,0.2,0.3)$, $(a_1,a_2)=(2,3)$ for which I am getting answer as $(A)$ but I am not sure that it is always true.If it is not true always then answer will be $(D).$ I don't know how to prove it formally. Please help.

Comment: Use AM-GM. First will be right answer.

Comment: Thank you @Love Invariants, got it..Now I can continue.

Comment: @LoveInvariants Why are you answering in a comment?

Comment: @Arthur-Because a hint would satisfy. OP should do the rest of the work. It helps askers very much.

Comment: @LoveInvariants Hints are still answers more than they are clarification requests. So they belong in answer posts, not in comments. Also, you have a direct answer to the question by saying which alternative was right, so calling it just a hint isn't quite right.

Comment: @Arthur-Ok. I have seen many people do it here.

Comment: @LoveInvariants I know. It's all too common.

Comment: @Arthur- I posted the answer. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be solved using the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality). We have the two sequences
$$
a_1, a_2, a_3,\ldots,a_n\\
\frac1{a_1}, \frac1{a_2},\frac1{a_3}, \ldots,\frac1{a_n}
$$
If we multiply each $a_i$ with $\frac1{a_i}$, then the sum is $n$. By the rearrangement inequality, this is the smallest possible value we can get, so rearranging must give us a result $\geq n$.

Or one may use the AM-GM inequality to get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use AM-GM. First will be right answer.
[AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)